# Is there a way to center app bar title by ignoring nav icon in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am developing a website with nuxt.js using vuetify. My problem is, on the app-bar, I have a nav icon and app-bar-title. The icon will appear on smaller screens than large screens. Whether the icon display or hidden, I want to center the title. However, when the icon is displayed, the title shifts and center the space after icon. Is there a way to do it without hard coding a space in title to balance?

Here is my code:

```html
<v-app-bar
  color="black"
  app
>
  <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="d-lg-none"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
  <v-spacer />
  <v-app-bar-title
    class="text-no-wrap text-h3"
    style="width: fit-content;">
    Title
  </v-app-bar-title>
  <v-spacer />
</v-app-bar>
```

Comment: Can you please show us a visual or maybe a repro?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have some overriding to do. First of all add the following classes to `<v-app-bar-title>`

```html
<v-app-bar-title
    class="text-h3 d-flex justify-center">
    Title
</v-app-bar-title>
```

Then in your main CSS file add the following class override:

```css
.v-app-bar-title__content {
  display: flex;
}
```